# Post-Infection Analysis of Suspected Keylogger

Tags: security, malware-removal, malware-detection

I've recently downloaded and ran a file, which I now suspect might be a keylogger. I am wondering how can I tell if this file is a keylogger? I can provide a link to the file if anyone would be able to reverse engineer it or decompile it and see if there is anything fishy inside.

I realize it is foolish of me to run a program I am not sure of, but it's already been done, so now I am trying to find out how to figure out if this file is infected with anything malicious or not

Thank you in advanced for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your file to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) for online analysis.

> What is VirusTotal
>
> VirusTotal, a subsidiary of Google, is a free online service that
>   analyzes files and URLs **enabling the identification of viruses, worms,
>   trojans and other kinds of malicious content** detected by antivirus
>   engines and website scanners. At the same time, it may be used as a
>   means to detect false positives, i.e. innocuous resources detected as
>   malicious by one or more scanners.

It checks the file using over 40 antivirus solutions.